# Ajax in ASPNET MVC: it runs but I think there's a better way to do

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a blog app where the user can insert comments to be approved/denied from the admin.

Here is the code for the View on which the administrator can give/deny approvation through Ajax:

```
<div id=news_comment_state_@(Model.Id)>@(Model.FlApproved?"Approved":"Denied")</div>
@Ajax.ActionLink("Approve", "ApproveDenyComment", new { IdComment = Model.Id, ApproveDeny=true }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "news_comment_state_"+@Model.Id})
<br />
@Ajax.ActionLink("Deny", "ApproveDenyComment", new { IdComment = Model.Id, ApproveDeny=false }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "news_comment_state_"+@Model.Id})
```

In the `Controller`, the `ApproveDenyComment` returns the `"Approve"/"Denied"` strings for the 2 actions.

It runs but I don't like it too much, I think there is a better and cleaner way to do it but I don't know it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cris,

I would be tempted to return a partialview via $ajax in respect to that user and repopulate the comments div. keeps everything consistent and saves error prone server/clientside logic disconnect (i.e. if the error status flag were to change in the future for whatever reason, then you're in trouble).

really has no peformance issues and many benefits in terms of consistency.

Answer (score 4):

why don't you return a JSON object upon the generated output, and as mentioned by @stack72 return bool to identify for true/false

check an example over here

[MVC JSON actions returning bool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3754324/mvc-json-actions-returning-bool)

and in this post it says that JSON object is a key value pair so use it for your action like <0, deny> and <1, approve>.

Answer (score 3):

Could you have 1 method that returns a bool value - this bool value can then be used to set the correct style on the view

you wouldnt then need to return magic strings

Answer (score 1):

Use $.ajax method call to the countroller and update the result on success. It's more efficient way than that.